# Click read more on a single and it takes you to items in a structure

Tags: sections

Hey guys I was wondering if anyone could help me...

I am trying to link from a readmore button in a single( it's like a services page) to pages in a structure.

So instead of having a top level services page in the structure, having it as a single and all the services together in a structure and linking to them from the single is this possible? if so, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any information from just about anywhere in craft. In fact, the only thing that distinguishes one 'page' from another is that craft conveniently populates a predefined 'entry' variable populated with the 'current' entry (EntryModel) using the template that you defined in your section settings. But you can choose to use that 'entry', ignore it, redefine it, or grab entirely different content altogether.

If I understand your requirements, it sounds like you are trying to create an 'index' page of sorts in your single, which links to entries in your structure.

```
<h1>{{ entry.title}}</h1>
{% set entries = craft.entries.sections('myStructureHandle').limit(null) %}
<ul>
    {% for entry in entries %}
        <li>
            <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ entry.description }}<br>
            <a href="{{ entry.url }}">Read more</p>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```